# Creating report winforms

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I'm trying to launch a report from a list with only 1 object in winforms. This is the code where I launch it.

```
    public InformePartido(List<Partido> partidos)
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        var reportDataSource = new ReportDataSource("Partido", partidos);
        reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource);
        reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
    }
```

I did these steps in the report wizard

[Step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOz3S.png), [Step 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tw2Wu.png), [Step 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0AOb.png)

And [this is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHjaL.png)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is `Partido` ?

Comment: What Type is `Partido`? It looks like it is already an Enumerable, in which case you do not want to make a `List` of them.

Comment: It is not enumerable, I designed better my code to this now, still no improvement

Comment: I changed my post with new code

Comment: Your screen shot shows `Partido` is selected as the dataset. It has been years since I used these types of reports but if you use `Partido` as the dataset I don't think you can then hand it a list of them. What happens if you give the `ReportDataSource` a single instance of `Partido` (not a list of one, a single instance)? Does it show the one item?

Comment: Needs to be enumerable, Im creating a class that has a list of Partido and let's see if it works